# Integration AdMob without Firebase: unwanted permissions (C2D)

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I'm porting an old game from AdMob to the latest AdMob with Firebase. I was using a deprecated version of AdMob.

I want the smallest integration as possible, I don't want Firebase analytics. I have a working integration (using Android Studio project), but when uploading my apk to Google Play, I realized new permissions were automatically added:

```
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
com.frozax.hashiextreme.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

What is this C2D thing? I don't want and don't need it. com.frozax.hashiextreme is the package name of my app. It looks like it's added from firebase-iid, but I don't want it either.

Is there a way to ignore these? I try to have as few permissions as possible.

In my dependecies, I only have

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'
```

I tried to remove

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

But it's not working and I still have these permissions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue.
As described in this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4kobvm/admob_firebase_and_extra_permissions/) you can add some lines to your manifest to avoid that:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your.app.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" tools:node="remove" />
```

But I definitively do not know if there will be an impact on Firebase integration.

Comment: In case another person gets the issue, I had to make sure my manifest had `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

I didn't see any apparent issue in the app itself, using only AdMob.

Comment: If you force these permissions out of your app, there could be unintended side-effects.  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/CXgecSxgsRE/kgkz7liJAwAJ

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson, let's continue the discussion in the google group thread.