# Exclude Firebase from Google Services 9.0.0

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I'm trying to get rid of Firebase because it's apparently included in latest Google Services. I'm using Analytics so I added this dependency to my `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
```

When I tried to update my app at Google Play I noticed two new (GCM) permissions

```
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
org.indywidualni.somepackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

I discovered they are added by new Services automatically because of Firebase. I don't use Firebase so I decided just to exclude it from project. How can I do it?

Comment: Here's a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/a/37459204/4388718 I want to do it even better. Just skip some unwanted parts of the library if it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

Include this lines in your app manifest file:

```
  <uses-permission
 android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"
 tools:node="remove" /> 
  <uses-permission
 android:name="com.somepackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
 tools:node="remove" />
```

To remove unwanted firebase classes include this in your gradle file:

```
 configurations {
     all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-common'
     all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
     all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid' }
```

Comment: How can we set version while removing dependencies? all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-common', version: '9.0.0' is not working!

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase team is currently recommending that you do not try to force Firebase permissions out of an app built with Firebase (although the Android tools make this possible).  Those extra permissions should not be causing problems.  There is [current discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/c2dm$20permission/firebase-talk/CXgecSxgsRE/kgkz7liJAwAJ) on this on the [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk) group.

If you have a very specific problem with these permissions (other than the fact that they exist), that's something we do need to know about, and you could file a bug report about that [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Not actually a problem with permissions only. With the whole Firebase and its services, receivers etc. I just don't use it and it's included to Analytics anyway. The app size is now 1 MB larger and a lot of unwanted stuff is starting with the app. I wanted analytics only. So I'm not updating to 9.0.0 for now. 8.4.0 is a better choice for me until I figure out how to remove this automatically added stuff in 9.0.0.

Comment: If you read the linked discussion on firebase-talk, you'll see that everything that appears unwanted is actually required by Firebase Analytics.  If you have a specific question about something that seems unnecessary, please let us know.

Comment: I've read it. But I'm taking about Google Analytics. Not Firebase Analytics. It's a separate service. So I'm still not using Firebase at all.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  It's a big context shift for me right now to think about situations where someone does not want Firebase in their app at all.  :-)  But I agree that the overhead is unwelcome and unnecessary, so I'll bring it up with folks here as an issue.

Comment: I took a quick look at your gradle build, and it looks like you can merge everything into one app with flavors for app and tv.  You could probably get rid of buildsystem/dependencies.gradle since it would all be the same app-level build.gradle.  You could pretty easily experiment with this in a test project to get a feel for how you can change configurations per flavor (each flavor can override things you would normally put in defaultConfig).

Comment: I'd like to chime in regarding the unwanted permissions. The main problem are the users of the apps. For example, flashlight apps got a bad press about having too many permissions and spying on their users a while back. The only permission required to run a flashlight is Camera, but with some Firebase integration, Storage and Phone dangerous permissions creep up. And suddenly a user starts wondering why does a flashlight app need to know anything about my phone or access my storage on my phone. This is the main issue of why these permissions are a problem for developers. Just my 2 cents.